# MySQL clause in where `case when`

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to figure it out but no solution at all.
My query :

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE owner = 'user'
AND (
    CASE WHEN status = 'NEW'
    THEN status = 'NEW'
    ELSE status IN ('CB','NA','NI','GC','FC')
    END
)
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

What I want to achieve is to show all records where `status` is `NEW` in an `Random order` limited by `one row` each, when no records `NEW` for the user the query needs to show the other `statuses`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE owner = 'user'
AND (CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table WHERE status = 'NEW') >= 1 THEN
                status = 'NEW'
     ELSE status IN ('CB','NA','NI','GC','FC')
     END)
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

**Demo**

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09b1c8/1

Comment: Ok this makes sense now. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

What i think, you can simply

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE owner = 'user'
AND (
   CASE WHEN status = 'NEW'
   THEN status = 'NEW'
   ELSE status IN ('CB','NA','NI','GC','FC')
   END
)
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

To

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE owner = 'user' AND status IN ('NEW','CB','NA','NI','GC','FC')
GROUP By some_id
ORDER BY RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Grouping doesn't matter, I have unique column 'phone_number', but it still doesn't matter because in an random order it will give different statuses.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
    WHERE owner = 'user'
      AND status IN ('NEW', 'CB','NA','NI','GC','FC')
    ORDER BY status = 'NEW' DESC,
             RAND() DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Will give you a total of 1 row, giving preference to a random 'NEW'.  If no 'NEW' rows, then a random one of the others.

(Please clarify your Question and provide sample output.)